# Anonymous Battery Removal - Side effects

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, power-on, shutdown

I am working with an embedded system with BeagleBone (White) as physical framework and Android JellyBean 4.1.2.

For some reasons I have to drop the entire power in the system (like anonymous battery removal).

Are there any side effects to doing this?

Like:

1. Issue with settings (not saving every time )
2. Database crash

or any other issues?